# Opening a .exe file from an AIR application and establishing a communication between the two

Tags: c++, flash, actionscript-3, air

I am trying to open a .exe file which is written in C++ from my AIR application. The .exe file just receives user input and outputs the same. I am using Native Process class in my AIR application and I am able to start the process and write the input to the standard input stream of the process( which is given by the event listener) but I am not receiving the echoed data from the standard output stream. All I receive is an output from the STANDARD_INPUT_PROGRESS event listener and then the statement "Press any key to continue.." which is normally displayed after a C++ application finishes execution.

The Actionscript code for my AIR application is as follows

```
import flash.desktop.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.filesystem.*;
var process:NativeProcess;

if(NativeProcess.isSupported){
   setupAndLaunch();
}
else
{
   trace("NativeProcess not supported.");
}

function setupAndLaunch():void
{
    var executablePath:String="C:/Interfacing.exe";
    var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();    
    var file:File=new File(String(executablePath));
    var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();

    nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable=file;
    process=new NativeProcess();
    process.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
    process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA,onOutputData);
    process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA,onErrorData);
    process.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT,onExit);
    process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_IO_ERROR,onIOError);
    process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_IO_ERROR,onIOError);
    process.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_IO_ERROR,onIOError);
    process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_INPUT_PROGRESS,standardInputProgress);

    process.standardInput.writeUTF("run \n");

 }

 function standardInputProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void
 {
    trace("standardInputProgress");
 }

 function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void
 {
    trace("Got:",process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));
 }

 function onErrorData(event:ProgressEvent):void
 {
    trace("ERROR -",process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable));
 }

 function onExit(event:NativeProcessExitEvent):void
 {
    trace("Process exited with ",event.exitCode);
 }

 function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
 {
    trace(event.toString());
 }
```

The C++ code is as follows:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int nNumberOfArgs,char* pszArgs[])
{   
char temp[80];
cin>>temp;
cout<<"The input recieved is "<<temp<<"\n";
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite familiar with this part of the library, but in general it's a good idea to add all listeners before you start the action - try moving your addEventListener-calls to before the start-call.

Comment: Also, nitpick; "which is normally displayed after a C++ application finishes execution." That has nothing to do with C++ or what it does normally, and everything to do with the line `system("PAUSE");`. Some IDE's will also make that happen so you have a chance to see the output of your program before the console window closes.